# Python to Insert IP's in specific format

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to write a code to put the IP addresses in this  format :

('1192.168.2.1','192.168.1.3',  ,,,,etc ) ('','','','','',   )  Basically all the IP's needs to be in this format  ( 'ip' , 'ip' )so I can run it ...

this is an example , but I have like thousands of IP's and I have them like this :
192.168.2.1
192.168.3.2
192.168.3.5

I decide to go with using for loop in python

ip =  (
192.168.2.1
192.168.3.2
192.168.3.5
)

for i in ip:
    print ("IP = " +='i',)

it says invalid syntax error ,,, I have many IPs  like this

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please explain this ( 192.168.2.1 192.168.3.2 192.168.3.5 )
what is it? is it a string?

anyhow, a simple solution of what i understood is to use split:

```
ips ='192.168.2.1 192.168.3.2 192.168.3.5'
ipsArray = ips.split()
print(ipsArray)
```

Just make sure to add a space between each ip, and the whole list of ips to be a string.

Hope this helps.